# Single line ggplot2 title with two fontsizes

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to emphasize the numbers in the title of the folowing plot:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggplot2)

dat <- subset(mtcars, wt > 2.75 & wt < 3.45)
dat$car <- rownames(dat)

p <- ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=car))+ 
  geom_label_repel(aes( fill=car), show.legend  = F) +

  labs(title = "numbers 1234 another thing")
p
```

It would be wonderful if i can get only the numbers with a different fontsize.
thans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An option is to use `ggtext` (which requires `ggplot2 >= 3.3.0`)

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(dat, aes(wt, mpg, label = car)) +
    geom_point(aes(color=car))+
    geom_label_repel(aes(fill = car), show.legend  = F) +
    ggtitle("numbers <span style='font-size:80pt'>1234</span> another thing") +
    theme(plot.title = element_markdown())
```

[image]